# Can the CBP at Vancouver Pacific Central station generate an electronic I-94?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, train-stations, vancouver, i-94

At several US land ports of entry, such as Blaine (coming from Vancouver by bus), although a paper I-94W form is always issued (pre-filled for those having an ESTA), officers are also able to generate an electronic I-94 (something I'd **emphatically** prefer for my own records, for example in case I were to lose the paper form somehow).

My question is: do the officers at the Vancouver Pacific Central station (where trains to Seattle depart from) have the facilities to do this as well?

Comment: Are paper I-94s not recorded in the database?

Comment: @phoog They haven't been historically AFAIK, and not all ports even have electronic equipment. For example, when entering from Montréal by bus, they have electronic equipment so that ESTA holders can get a pre-filled I-94W, whereas when entering from Montréal by train there is no equipment, so everyone has to fill out the form by hand, rendering the ESTA useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Called preclerance at Vancouver airport (who also conduct the US checks at the train station).

Turns out, at the Pacific Central station, as well as in Blaine, I-94Ws have been **abolished altogether** for ESTA holders, and they get an entry stamp+electronic admission record just like when entering by air.

Comment: Do you have a source for this information?

Comment: @phoog The horse's mouth. Called them on +1-604-278-7422